# How to check HLS feed is still live or not

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a `m3u8` feed, i'm looking for a way to detect if it's still working or not using `Javascript`.
when i fetch the url i still get a list fo all chunks, but the live is stoped a long time ago. and the player is not playing it.
so i'm wondering if there is a way to check if the `m3u8` feed is still live, without trying it on the player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common live stream behavior is that every `x` seconds a new segment is made available, i.e. gets added at the end of the playlist.

So what you could do is load the playlist once, then wait `x` seconds and load it again. If the live stream is still running the last segment in the playlist should have changed (i.e. shifted upwards).

Regarding how long to wait:
When you load the playlist initially you'll see an `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` tag in the playlist specifying the maximum segment duration. So if we wait for at least one target duration before we reload then at least one new segment must have been added.

#### Example:

1. Initial load:

   ```
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
    #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/0.ts
    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/1.ts
    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/2.ts
   ```
2. Wait 8 seconds, hence `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8`
3. Second load:

   ```
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
    #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1

    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/1.ts
    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/2.ts
    #EXTINF:8.0,
    https://priv.example.com/3.ts
   ```

#### Sidenote

The above example is a sliding-window live stream, i.e. segments at the top of the playlist drop out and `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` gets incremented. In that case, checking if `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` changes would be an option. However, if the playlist specifies an `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE` of `EVENT` then no segments would drop out at the top [1] `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` would not change. The method of checking the last segment, however, works in any case.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.3.5

#### EDIT

The HLS spec further states:

> If a Media Playlist does not contain the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag, the
> server MUST make a new version of the Playlist file available that
> contains at least one new Media Segment.  It MUST be made available
> relative to the time that the previous version of the Playlist file
> was made available: no earlier than one-half the target duration
> after that time, and no later than 1.5 times the target duration
> after that time.  This allows clients to utilize the network
> efficiently.

So actually we have to wait at least 1.5 times the target duration until we reload.